# Why is the form value object empty?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

Help please understand. I'm trying to write a custom validator for a reactive form.

component:

```
private form: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit() {
    const this_ = this;

    this.form = new FormGroup({
      'email':      new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
      'password':   new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]),
      'password2':  new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6), this_.comparePasswords]),
      'name':       new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
      'agree':      new FormControl(false, [Validators.requiredTrue])
    });
  }

  comparePasswords(c: FormControl) {
    console.log(c);

    const hashStr = Md5.hashStr(c.value.password);
    const hashStr2 = Md5.hashStr(c.value.password2);

    console.log(hashStr, hashStr2);

    return (hashStr === hashStr2) ? null : {
      comparePasswords: {
        valid: false
      }
    };
  }
```

All the imports that you need to connect. After loading the page, the browser console immediately displays the form object, in which the value object is null.

I can not make check in the function comparePasswords().

Console display follow:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'password' of null

[LIVE EXAMPLE HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s2k8rq?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Instead of new formcontrol with a default password value of null, why don't you set the default value to an empty string `""`? I bet that's the issue.

Comment: Sorry I answered without seeing @I.R.R. comment

Answer (score 3):

Change `null` to `""`

```
this.form = new FormGroup({
  'email':      new FormControl("", [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
  'password':   new FormControl("", [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]),
  'password2':  new FormControl("", [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6), this_.comparePasswords]),
  'name':       new FormControl("", [Validators.required]),
  'agree':      new FormControl(false, [Validators.requiredTrue])
});
```

Comment: Did you run this code with OP's test link and verified it solves the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Besides giving the initial value as `null`, you are setting your custom validator on the formcontrol, so what you actually get in your custom validator is just the formcontrol `password2`, **not** the entire formgroup.

I would therefore place the custom validator at formgroup level, or better yet, create a nested formgroup for the passwords and apply the validator for that. Why? Since if you apply the validator on the whole form, it will be fired whenever **any** changes happen to form. But in this sample, I apply it on the whole form as well as minified your code. Also the advantage to applying a custom validator on a formgroup level (nested or not) will take care of both checking the inputs. As your validator sits in your question it will only check if the `password2` matches `password` whenever changes happens to the `password2` field. So what happens if you modify the `password` field after modifying `password2`, an error is not showed, and form is considered valid.

So build form as such:

```ts
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.form = this.fb.group({
    password:   ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]],
    password2:  ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]],
  },{validator: this.comparePasswords});
}
```

Then your custom validator would look like this:

```ts
comparePasswords(c: FormGroup) {
  const hashStr = Md5.hashStr(c.controls.password.value);
  const hashStr2 = Md5.hashStr(c.controls.password2.value);
  return (hashStr === hashStr2) ? null : { notSame: true };
}
```

You could compare just `c.controls.password.value` and `c.controls.password2.value` but since you are using `Md5`, I just used those values here. Also notice that we are just sending an object with some custom error of your choosing, here `notSame` if the passwords do not match.

And to display the error message you can do:

```html
<div *ngIf="form.hasError('notSame')">Passwords do not match!</div>
```

Your modified **[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxzdwn?file=app/app.component.html)**